# program wont work after being compiled with py2exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, dropbox-api, py2exe

I wrote a program it works fine without any errors when I run it from the python interpreter, I then used py2exe to turn it in to an .exe but when I run it it does'nt work anymore... I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "pass.py", line 1, in <module>
 File "dropbox\__init__.pyc", line 3, in <module>
 File "dropbox\client.pyc", line 22, in <module>
 File "dropbox\rest.pyc", line 26, in <module>
 File "pkg_resources.pyc", line 950, in resource_filename
 File "pkg_resources.pyc", line 1638, in get_resource_filename
NotImplementedError: resource_filename() only supported for .egg, not .zip
```

Am I supposed to do something when using py2exe when I have downloaded modules imported into the program?
these are the modules imported :

```
import dropbox
import os
import getpass
from time import sleep
```

please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem using the solution found [here](http://mfctips.com/2013/05/03/dropbox-python-sdk-with-py2exe-causes-notimplementederror-resource_filename-only-supported-for-egg-not-zip/)

basically you modify ~line 26 in rest.py found in the dropbox library
to this:

```
try:  
    TRUSTED_CERT_FILE = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, 'trusted-certs.crt')
except:  
    # if current module is frozen, use library.zip path for trusted-certs.crt path
    # trusted-certs.crt must exist in same directory as library.zip
    if hasattr(sys,'frozen'):
        resource_name = sys.prefix
        resource_name.strip('/')
        resource_name += '/trusted-certs.crt'
        TRUSTED_CERT_FILE = resource_name
    else:
        raise
```

and then place the trusted-certs.crt file also found in the dropbox library in the same folder as your executable

Comment: Thanks this is what I had done to solve the problem, I will accept your answer anyways in case someone needs it as it was not easy finding the solution